# Yammer Videos take a long time to play

Tags: video, video-streaming, yammer

We are having an issue with our clients where any video uploaded to Yammer takes a long time to start playing, minimum 8 minutes even for a short video. This only happens while on our internal network. If I take my laptop home, or put it on an aircard the issue is resolved. I have tested this on all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari), all browsers have the same issue. I have updated to the most resent version of Flash Player.

After much testing, we were able to identify the root cause, but we haven't been able to come up with a fix.

Scenario:
Sign into Yammer and establish an HTTPS session through the proxy server on port xxxx (we redirect port 80 and port 443 to a proxy specific port).
Click on a Yammer video and hit play.
At this point Wireshark shows that something attempts to hit port 1935 over and over again. This is the attempt to setup the RTMP stream. I'm not exactly sure what is attempting to do this, is it the Flash Player plugin in the browser? This continues for about 2 -3 minutes. Currently we have the firewall setup to do a silent drop on these requests, we have tried replying with an RST packet, but it didn't help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/koBtu.jpg

After it finally gives up on port 1935, it then attempts port 443 for another 2 to 3 minutes. This tells me that whatever is attempting to start the video is not aware of our client side proxy settings for some reason, as the 443 port should be redirected by the client to port xxxx proxy port.

After that gives up, it kind of just sits there for another 2 minutes and then finally I see streaming traffic on the existing, original HTTPS tunnel that all the other Yammer traffic is using.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZubF.jpg

Does anyone have any idea what we might do to speed this up? I'm sure there are other companies that block port 1935 outbound. Can someone Wireshark and see what the firewall is responding with and how long it takes to give up on 1935. I'm sure if we can figure that out, we can set the attempts on unauthenticed 443 to respond the same way, which should give us a very fast fail and then the video will use the existing stream as it should be.

Thanks!
BJ

Comment: Crap, my photo sharing doesn't seem to have worked. I'll try to find somewhere to host those photos.

Comment: Changed the photos to imgur.com and they are working now. Another note, if we open port 1935 outbound from all client IP addresses on the firewall, the problem is resolved and the video stream sets up on port 1935 via RTMP. The reason security is not happy with that is because there is no way to authenticate the traffic and our firewall doesn't have deep packet inspection for RTMP. So if we open that, a compromised system would be able to do a simple port scan, find that TCP 1935 is wide open and send out a payload. So we need this traffic to go through the proxy.

Comment: It should also be noted that Blue Coat proxies offer a Flash Video agent that would probably fix our issue, but our hardware is not new enough to run the agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firewall must be reconfigured to support it. This problem is not unique to Yammer; it will be the case for any Flash Server sites that you need to connect to. If you take a look at the Adobe site for Flash Server you can see the order of the ports and how/when they're tried.

http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/ports-firewalls-flash-media-server.html

The solution in this case is going to be changing the firewall. Flash Player itself will not respect proxy settings. There's another stackoverflow message about this:

serverfault.com/questions/264079/force-rtmp-streams-playing-flash-to-be-requested-via-proxy-server

As well as this, you can visit the Flash Player configuration page to see what your options are for configuring Flash. There are no proxy settings.

http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html

It's possible that you could use something like Squid-Cache (squid-cache.org) to capture and redirect the traffic, but that would depend on your specific setup.